# EF - Navegar atravez de ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Possuo a seguinte classe em uma aplicação a fins de pratica de C# com EntityFramework:

```
public class Livro
{
    public Livro()
    {
        Autor = new HashSet<Autor>();            
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public int GeneroId { get; set; }
    public int AutorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Autor> Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Genero Genero { get; set; }
}
```

Quando quero acessar os atributos da classe `Genero`, faço como se fosse uma classe normal: `Genero.Nome`, `Genero.Id`, etc... Agora, pela classe `Autor`, como é uma coleção, eu nao consigo o mesmo resultado.

Queria saber como fazer para navegar pela `ICollection<Autor> Autor` para acessar seus atributos.

Obrigado.

Comment: Porque você tem uma lista de Autores da classe Autor, mas a sua classe Livro possui um AutorId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentaram, o seu relacionamento 1 para N esta errado. A chave estrangeira deveria ficar dentro de Author, já que é o Author quem deve saber qual o livro ao qual ele se relaciona.

Sobre a coleção, `ICollection` não possui muitas maneiras de percorrer seus valores. Então, a melhor forma de navegar por sua coleção é utilizando um foreach (caso não queira percorrer toda, pode utilizar um `for`):

```
foreach(var prop in Author) {
    prop.Titulo = "Teste";
}
```

Existe a API do LINQ que ajuda bastante a fazer consultas dentro de coleções parecido com as soluções que você encontra em linguagem SQL. Caso queira um valor especifico pode pesquisar ele utilizando o FirstOrDefault:

```
var meuAutor = Author.FirstOrDefault(prop => prop.Id == 1);
return meuAutor.Titulo; //Caso ele não ache, o valor Default é null e vai dar exceção.
```

Se você quer apenas percorrer sua lista, o foreach é mais do que suficiente. Caso queira fazer manipulações maiores na sua coleção, você pode converter sua ICollection para uma IList e fazer a manipulação dele utilizando index.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Gabriel.

Comment: @MatheusDaumas se a resposta satisfaz a sua pergunta, você pode marcá-la como correta. :)

Answer (score 0):

Será necessário acessar item por item, e isso pode ser feito através de qualquer laço de repetição (*for, foreach, while*...).

Além do mais, para que seja possível estabelecer uma relação de 1:N, não faz muito sentido ter uma coleção de autores e não ter uma coleção com seus respectivos IDs.